# Loading new operation in Tensorflow - AlreadyExistsError

Tags: python, tensorflow, new-operator

I'm loading a new operation in Tensorflow (in the standard way), namely:

```
import tensorflow as tf
...
select_module = tf.load_op_library('./pixel_selector.so')
```

and I'm getting the following error when running the script:

```
File "........./load_library.py", line 64, in load_op_library
None, None, error_msg, error_code)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.AlreadyExistsError: 
Op with name PixelSelector
```

Is anyone getting the same error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a race condition, which can be solved with:

```
os.system('mkdir -p {}'.format( summaries_directory ))
```

You can track the issue [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7448).

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
Actually I do not see why it should be a race condition, since the loading of the library is done at the beginning of the file and that instruction is not inside any loop!

Comment: Is it possible that in your case you're loading this library more than once? To test this, you could add some logging just before your load_library call and check it that way.

Comment: yes, the library was loaded more than once, becuase it was appearing twice in the shared object file (due to wrong setup in compilation). Thanks @PeteWarden!